# Show that the function $F:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x^{p}}f(t)dt$ is concave

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a concave function with $p \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

a) Show that $f$ is integrable on every interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$.

b) Show that the function $F:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x^{p}}f(t)dt$ is concave.

I know there is a theoren that says if a function is concave an a closed interval, then the function is continuous on the open interval. This theorem would prove instantly $a)$, but I wonder if there is an alternative way. For $b)$ I tried starting the problem with the definition of concavity for f and nothing. Then I tried using the previous theorem and working with $F$ as a differentiable function on a arbitrary open interval but I couldn't finish. I wonder why they say $p$ is between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Ok that means $x^{p}$ is concave and maybe we can use that for the function F, but why not $p$ upper bounded by $1$?. The function $F$ is actually a composition of a primitive of $f$ which is $0$ in $x=0$ and the function $x^{p}$. Clearly the primitive of $f$ is increasing and positive (using the previous theorem and working on an arbitrary bounded open interval). I even tried using Hermite-Hadamard inequality, but nothing.

Comment: Why is $f$ intergrable near $0$?

Comment: The function $f$ is bounded from below and concave, hence, it is bounded on any bounded interval and therefore integrable on any bounded interval (well technically you'd still need to prove that the integral makes sense).

Answer (score 2):

For (b), the condition that $p \leq 1/2$ is necessary.
Consider $f(t) = t$ and $p = 3/4$, which renders $F(x) = x^{3/2}/2$, which is not concave.

First, we show the $p = 1/2$ case.
Notice that $F$ is differentiable, with
$$
F'(x) = f(x^{1/2})\cdot \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}.
$$

For $F$ to be convex, it is enough to show that $F'$ is decreasing, for which in turn it is enough to show that $g(y) = 2F'(y^2) = f(y)/y$ is decreasing (since the function $x \mapsto x^{1/2}$ is increasing).

Now, let $0 \leq x \leq y$, from which we can write $x$ as a convex combination of $0$ and $y$ according to
$$
x
= \Bigl(1 - \frac{x}{y}\Bigr)\cdot 0 + \frac{x}{y}\cdot y.
$$

Since $f$ is concave, we have that
\begin{gather*}
f(x)
\geq  \Bigl(1 - \frac{x}{y}\Bigr)\cdot f(0) + \frac{x}{y}\cdot f(y). \\
g(x)
= \frac{f(x)}{x}
\geq \frac{f(y)}{y}
= g(y).
\end{gather*}

Thus $g$, and so $F'$ is decreasing, from which $F$ is concave.

Now, for $0 \leq p \leq 1/2$, we have
$$
F_p(x)
= F(x^{2p}).
$$

Since $p \leq 1/2$, this is a composition of concave increasing functions and so is itself concave.

Comment: Your answer is indeed a very good solution. I do have two questions though. Why did you study the case of p = 1/2 separately? And what do you mean by $F_p(x)= F(x^{2p}).$? Thank you!